# Salesforce SOQL set batchsize in REST api

Tags: rest, salesforce, soql

Is there a way to set the batch size to 2000 (maximum)? I know it is possible via soap API by adding an option: [see here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm)

Is there a way to achieve this via REST API POST request?

Comment: See also here:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/rest-api-queryoptions-batchsize

Answer (score 1):

You can set the REST batch size using option headers:

> **Field name**
>
> Sforce-Query-Options
>
> **Field values**
>
> batchSize — A numeric value
> that specifies the number of records returned for a query request.
> Child objects count toward the number of records for the batch size.
> For example, in relationship queries, multiple child objects may be
> returned per parent row returned. The default is 2,000; the minimum is
> 200, and the maximum is 2,000. There is no guarantee that the
> requested batch size will be the actual batch size; this is done to
> maximize performance.
>
> **Example**
>
> Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize=1000

**Docs:** http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/headers_queryoptions.htm